# React: following DRY in React when fetching data from API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dry

When I am fetching the data from API, If I get Ok I will render the component to display the data,
If an error has occured, I want to display a custom message for different components, and during fetching the data I want to show a loading message.

```
 export default function App() {
  const { data: products, loading, error } = useFetch(
    "products?category=shoes"
  );

  

  if (error) return <div>Failed to load</div>;
  if (loading) return <div>wait is Loading</div>;

  return (
    <>
      <div className="content">
          <section id="products">{products.map((product) =>{return <div>product.name</div>})}</section>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

I am planning to have a fetch call in multiple components. So, I was thinking If I could write the above logic in one place, like an HOC or Rendered Props and reuse it.

**What I tried: but failed**
HOC wont work because you cant call hooks in normal functions. It has to be a Component.
Rendered Props wont work as it gives this error:
**Error: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render.**

**Below is my failed rendered props code**

```
const ShowData= function ({ data: products }) {
  
  return (
    <div>
  {products.map(product => {return <div>product.name</div>})}
  </div>
  );
};

function SearchCount({ count }) {
  return <h3>Search Results: {count} items found</h3>;
}

const Wrapper = function () {
  return (
    <LoadingAndError
      render={ShowData}
      params={{ url: "products?category=shoes" }}
    ></LoadingAndError>
  );
};

export default Wrapper;
```

Loading and error logic is moved to the LoadingAndError component

```
const LoadingAndError = function (props) {

  const { url } = props.params;
  const { data: products, loading,error} = useFetch(url);
  if (loading)
    return <h1>Loading</h1>;
  if (error) return <h1>Error</h1>;

  return props.render({ data: products });
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return props.render({ data: products });
```

This line is calling `props.render` as a function, but you've passed in a component. Calling component directly can cause exactly the error you're seeing. If you want `props.render` to be used like this, then you should pass in a function which creates an element, like this:

```
<LoadingAndError
  render={(props) => <ShowData {...props} />}
  params={{ url: "products?category=shoes" }}
></LoadingAndError>
```

Alternatively, if you want to keep passing in `render={ShowData}`, then change loadingAndError to create an element:

```
const loadingAndError = function (props) {
  const { url } = props.params;
  const { data: products, loading,error} = useFetch(url);
  if (loading)
    return <h1>Loading</h1>;
  if (error) return <h1>Error</h1>;

  const Component = props.render
  return <Component data={products}/>
}
```